# Trouble outputting letter grade

Tags: c++

Currently i have achieved all goals for this program except outputting my letter graded average. Right now it always outputs a 70 and not a letter grade. Does anyone see what my issue is? I know currently that its redefining my lettergrade value into a 70 after passing through the lettergrade function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;




int getexams(int count)
{
    cout << "Number of exams to be entered:";
    cin >> count;

    if (count > 1024)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number below 1024." << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return count;

}

int enterexams(int name[],int count, int b)
{

    int numexams = count;
    for (int a = 0;a < numexams;a++)
    {
        cout << "Enter grades: ";
        cin >> name[a]; 
        b++;
    }
    return b;

}


char letter(double average, char lettergrade)
{
    int x;
    x = average;
    if (x >= 90) {
        lettergrade = 'A';

    }
    else if (x >= 80) {
        lettergrade = 'B';

    }
    else if (x >= 70) {
        lettergrade = 'C';

    }
    else if (x >= 60) {
        lettergrade = 'D';

    }
    else {
        lettergrade = 'F';

    }
    return lettergrade;


}
void output(int count,int name[], double average, int lettergrade)
{
    cout << "Number of exams: " << count << endl;
    for (int a = 0;a < count;a++)
        cout << "Exam grades: " << name[a] << endl;
    cout << "Average grade: " << average << endl;
    cout << "Letter grade: " << lettergrade << endl;
}
int averagecalc(int average,int count,int name[])
{
    int a,sum,x;
    sum = 0;

    for (a = 0;a < count;a++)
    {
        sum += name[a];

    }
    average = sum / count;
    return average;
}
int main()
{
    char lettergrade = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int total = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int count =0;
    count = getexams(count);
    // Number of exams

    int exams = count;
    const int x = exams;            // Exam Values
    int name[1024];

    enterexams(name,count,b);
    average = averagecalc(average,count,name);
    lettergrade = letter(average, lettergrade);
    output(count, name, average, lettergrade);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Can you print out the value of X in your lettergrade function before the IF-statements. What is the output?

Comment: Outputs a 50 after defining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `output` function is defined like this:

```
void output(/*stuff*/ int lettergrade)
```

Here `lettergrade` is *an integer*, but you want it to be a `char`, so you should change the definition accordingly.

Comment: To expand, the ASCII character 'F' has a decimal code of 70

Comment: Thanks, simple mistake but i didn't notice it after many lookovers.